# Getting two different answers for $\int \frac 1 {2x-2}dx$

Tags: integration, solution-verification

When I tried to compute the integral $\int \frac 1 {2x-2}dx$, the following was my attempt. $$\int \frac 1 {2x-2}dx=\frac 1 2 \int \frac 1 {x-1}dx=\frac 1 2\ln\left(|x-1|\right)+c$$

But then I saw someone on youtube doing the same integral and getting the answer $$\int \frac 1 {2x-2}dx=\frac 1 2 \ln\left(|2x-2|\right)+c$$

Now I immediately thought that something was wrong, so I tried to put the [integral into Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2x-2%7D?or=input). To my surprise, Symbolab seemed to agree with the second answer. Then I put the [integral into Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+1%2F%282x-2%29) and I got the answer that I had at first.

After that I decided to input the following into Symbolab. [$$\int \frac 1 2 \cdot\frac 1 {x-1}dx$$](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Ccdot%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx-1%7Ddx?or=input) and Symbolab seemed to agree with my first answer.

Now, it could be possible that I am missing something very obvious, but I don't know what is it. So, am I wrong or was Symbolab wrong?

Comment: $\log(2x-2)=\log 2+\log(x-1)$ And then combine the $\log 2$ term with your added constant $+C$

Comment: @FrankW Yeah, didn't think about that! Thanks!

Comment: Reminds me of $\int2\tan(x)\sec(x)\sec(x)\,dx$. Use $u=\tan(x)$ and you get $\tan^2(x)+C$. Use $u=\sec(x)$ and you get $\sec^2(x)+C$.

Comment: Check all answers will differ by a constant.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that an antiderivative (= indefinite integral) is defined only up to the sum of a constant, thus:

$$\frac12\ln|2x-2|=\frac12\left(\ln2+\ln|x-2|\right)+c=\frac12\ln|x-2|+C$$

with $\;c,\,C\;$ arbitrary constants.

Comment: Didn't think about combining them, Thanks!